# If there exists an integrable function that is not zero a.e., then the measure is $\sigma$-finite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f\in L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $f(x)\neq 0$ for almost every $x\in \Omega$. How to prove $\mu$ is $\sigma-$finite?

I only got that $\Omega=\cup_{n=1}^\infty \{x\in \Omega:|f(x)|\geq \frac{1}{n}\}\cup \{{ x\in \Omega: f(x)=0\}} $, because $\mu\{x\in \Omega:|f(x)|\geq \frac{1}{n}\}\leq n||f||_1<\infty,\ \ \mu\{x\in \Omega:f=0\}=0$, so $\Omega$ is $\sigma-$finite.

But how it works to deal with ''$\mu$ is $\sigma-$finite''?

Comment: what is the relation between $f$ and $\mu$?

Comment: $f$ is integrable w.r.t $\mu$, so at least $f$ is measurable.

Comment: You're done? You've shown that the space $\Omega$ is a countable union of measurable sets of finite measure under $\mu$, so the space is $\sigma$-finite under $\mu$.

Comment: eh....What is the difference between space is $\sigma-$ finite and $\mu$ is $\sigma-$ finite

Comment: There *is* no difference, except that saying $\Omega$ is σ-finite is somewhat sloppy, since σ-finiteness is really a property of the measure, not of the underlying space. (But we all indulge in such sloppiness of language sometimes.) If you want to be *really* pedantic, σ-finiteness is a property of $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, and everything else is shorthand.

Comment: Try to give more descriptive titles to your questions. I see that the last eight of them all begin with "how to prove". These words  are not really necessary; it's better to describe the statement to be proved in more details.

Comment: OK, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you observed, in the decomposition 
$$\Omega=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left\{x\in \Omega:|f(x)|\geq \frac{1}{n}\right\}\cup \{{ x\in \Omega: f(x)=0\}}$$
every set on the right  has finite measure. Therefore, the measure is $\sigma$-finite.

If needed, one can also be more precise and say: "$\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite on $\Omega$", or (not as often) "$\Omega$ is a  $\sigma$-finite set for $\mu$".

Comment: why does every set on the right have finite measure

Comment: @DavidWarrenKatz  that is derived from the property of f.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E_n = \{x \in \Omega | n \le f(x) < n + 1\}$ and let $m_n = min_{x \in E_n} { f(x)}$.

Now, if $\mu(E_n) = \infty$ for any n, then $\int_{\Omega} |f| \ge \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} \mu (E_n) m_n = \infty$, , contradicting that f is integrable.